# C# web api request allow only for listed domains

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have web api hosted on api.domain.com and my app is in app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com

I want to allow api.domain.com should be accessed only from app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com

how to achieve this? I have tried with allow access control but i don't want to show the allowed domain's in browser cosole

and also when i access api.domain.com through browser should show 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Please help

Comment: You have to enable CORS (Cross origin) support for the api endpoint. See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 1):

More specifically to my comment above. You have to enable CORS support for the api endpoint controller.

- Add CORS to the VS project
- Then use the `[EnableCors(origins: "https://app1.domain.com,https://app2.domain.com")]` attribute on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IP and Domain restrictions features of IIS. This feature needs to be installed explicitly.

[image]

Comment: that denying all request please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339424/iis-ipsecurity-with-webapi-request-gives-access-control-allow-origin-error

Comment: @aas :Controlling access through CORS will work only when service/api is accessed directly from browser.

Comment: as your answer i have tried and is not working it is denied the all request except allowed ip that means when i allow app1.domain.com ip and request from my browser is denied but when i request from app1.doamin.com server browser is allowed but i don't want like that. I need as i asked in the question